# characters missing in javascript replace function vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am using the replace method as follows:

```
<code v-html="'/<test>/'.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, 'testing')"></code>
```

I have a larger string that I am testing against with many `\n` but I noticed with the above replace function to remove these characters, somehow the value `<test>` inside `//` gets replaced.

Answer (score 2):

The `/<test>/` string isn't turning into `//`, it's being rendered by the [v-html](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vue-js-v-html-directive/) directive. To more accurately test your replace method I'd recommend using the [v-text](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-text) directive instead.

Below is a demonstration of the difference in output between the two directives.

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>Using v-html</p>
  <code v-html="'/<test>/'.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, 'testing')"></code>
  <br/>
  <p>Using v-text</p>
  <code v-text="'/<test>/'.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, 'testing')"></code>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I think what's happening is that html is trying to render <test>, so that is why it is blank. The regex isn't actually doing anything there, but rather html is trying to render this as a tag.

Comment: But how do you render the new lines then, where previously I was replacing them.

Comment: I'm unsure of what your goal is. Your original question is attempting to replace newline characters with the string 'testing' Are you trying to replace newline characters with a line break `<br/>` instead?